Flask-SocketIO - Method Not Allowed
I have a program that generates notes based on a topic, using OpenAI's API. I am using Flask-SocketIO to make it happen in real time on the website. I send the request to the API by clicking a button on the website, and it is supposed to update the InnerHTML of a div to the However, when I click the button, it comes up with an error on screen and in the console:
Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 405 (METHOD NOT ALLOWED)
I am also getting another error in the console, when I first submit the form to generate the notes:
WebSocket connection to 'ws://127.0.0.1:5000/socket.io/' failed: Invalid frame header
Here is my code:
script.js
var socket = io('http://127.0.0.1:5000/');
socket.on('connect', function() {
    console.log('connected')
});

function createSpan() {
    var c = 1
    var subheadings = []
    for (let i of document.getElementsByTagName('li')) { // This iterates through each subheading
        blankSpace = document.createElement('div');
        blankSpace.id = 'p' + c;
        var buttonTxt = i.innerHTML;
        subheadings.push(buttonTxt)
        genNotesBtn.onclick = function() {
            socket.emit('notesGen', { text: subheadings[c-1], targetId: blankSpace.id });
        }
        c++;
    }
}

socket.on('notes', function(data) {
    var targetElement = document.getElementById(data.targetId);
    if (targetElement) {
        targetElement.innerHTML = data.notes;
    }
});

app.py
from flask import Flask, render_template, request
from flask_socketio import SocketIO, emit

app = Flask(__name__)
socketio = SocketIO(app)

@app.route('/')
def index():
    return render_template('index2.html')

@socketio.on('notesGen')
def notesGen(data):
    detail = request.form.get('detailSelectorDropdown') # Gets data from a form asking about the level of detail the notes should be.
    threadid = notesGenThread(data.get('text'), detail)
    notes = notesGenRun(threadid)
    print('received notesGen event with data: ' + str(data.get('text')))
    emit('notes', {'notes': notes, 'targetId': data['targetId']})

if __name__ == '__main__':
    socketio.run(app, debug=True)

I changed the data I was emitting to JSON, however this did not make a difference. Furthermore, the socket.on function in script.js was originally inside the function, however I put it outside. Once again this didn't make a difference.

always put FULL error message (starting at word "Traceback") in question (not in comments) as text (not screenshot, not link to external portal). There are other useful information in the full error/traceback.

you could create minimal working code (with minimal HTML and without notesGenThread) so we could simply copy and run it.
